# Under what conditions can I orthogonally diagonalize a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, diagonalization, orthogonal-matrices

I know that you can orthogonally diagonalize a matrix if it's symmetric.
Under what other conditions can I orthogonally diagonalize a matrix?
And if a matrix is diagonalizable, is it orthogonally diagonalizable?

Comment: Do you know the concept of a [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix) matrix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any matrix that is orthogonally diagonalizable (in the conventional usage of this term) is necessarily symmetric. Indeed, if $A = UDU^T$ for an orthogonal matrix $U$ and a real, diagonal matrix $D$, then
$$
A^T = (UDU^T)^T = U^{TT}D^TU^T = UDU^T = A.
$$
A matrix that is diagonalizable will not necessarily be orthogonally diagonalizable. For instance, the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&2\\0&3}
$$
is diagonalizable, as we could deduce from the fact that it $2 \times 2$ with $2$ distinct, real eigenvalues.  However, since $A$ is not symmetric, it cannot be orthogonally diagonalizable.